# Showing Multiple Lines in a JOptionPane

Tags: java, arraylist, joptionpane

So basically what I'm doing is get the all entries from an arraylist and show them in a JOptionPane window. But the problem is that a new JOPtionPane is opening everytime for every entry. Is there a way where I can list all entries in one JOptionPane ?? Thank you.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < LoansList.size(); i++)
{
    Loans myLoans = (Loans) LoansList.get(i);                     

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, myLoans.showDetails() + "\n ",
    "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing it like this:

```
String acc = "";

for (int i = 0; i < LoansList.size(); i++)
{
    Loans myLoans = (Loans) LoansList.get(i); 

    acc += myLoans.showDetails () + "\n";
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, acc, "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: @AndreaParascandalo If this solved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted. PS: You're welcome :) .

Comment: If I want to add a Title Like this


This line stays constant >> Name Surname Address Telephone
This line changes        >> Var   Var     Var     Var


Where should I put the title text ? So the entries of the arraylist are neatly put under the corresponding title ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, then in the code I wrote above you should change this `String acc="";` to this: `String = "Name Surname Address Telephone" + "\n";`. I hope it works. PS: If you want more flexibility in displaying this information, you should put in in a `JPanel` and use a `JDialog` to display it. This way you could use Layout Managers, like `GridLayout` (which is perfect for what you need).